# Pentaho Data Validator Error : Unable to find the specified fieldname for validation

Tags: validation, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration, data-quality

I'm working on a transformation in PDI using data validation but i get this error when i run my transormation, can anyone help me fix it:
edit: I do have that field but it says unable find it.

```
2021/04/23 21:59:10 - DataValidation - Dispatching started for transformation [DataValidation]
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 - Unable to find the specified fieldname 'CREDAT_0' for validation#1
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 - 
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.validator.Validator.processRow(Validator.java:111)
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2021/04/23 21:59:11 - Data validator.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The error already informed you regarding your error that "Unable to find the specified fieldname 'CREDAT_0' for validation#1"

Comment: Yes i got it, but i do have that field i just don't know why it can't find it

Comment: In that case, you need to share your transformation/ job for investigation.

Comment: You are not giving enough details, but first thing I would check is if the fieldname is correct. Is all uppercase, all lowercase, or a mix? That is a common point for errors. The "_0" would also be a suspect depending on your previous steps.

Comment: I have the same field in 2 files, so i tried using 2 data validator ( one for each file ) and it worked